# Can I exclude the bottom row from a Filter in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets, there is a header and 13 rows containing data.

There is then a row containing the average of the cells above.

I'd like to be able to sort the various columns in order of size, unfortunately whenever I try to do this the "Averages"  row is sorted along with them.

Is there any way to exclude the bottom row from the filter?

Comment: Welcome. This sounds  like a design error. Why not just put the averages _above_ the header row?

Comment: That works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a range of cells to which to apply a filter.

Make sure filtering is turned off. Then select the header row and the data rows - but not the "Averages" row - and click the filter button to turn on filtering. Now the filter will only apply to the data rows.

Note that this will simply leave the "Averages" row visible, it won't make the averages match the visible rows in the filtered data. To do that you can make use of the [SUBTOTAL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649?hl=en) function with function code 101.